# Error 424 when trying to delete element in array vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I was trying to delete the specific element in the array vba when certain condition are true but i end up getting error 424. May I know the right way to do it? I tired to use redim, however it doesn't suit my condition as after the comparing with others array i need to store the data back into excel file where the location in the excel file is already sorted.

Before changing the remarkRange to array variant, I used it as **Dim remarkRange 
 As Range** where I can just use **.Clear** to clear the range item in a specific element.

I tried `remarkRange(I, 1)=" "` it runs without error but im not sure if its suitable.  May I know the correct way to do it? Thanks.

```
Dim remarkRange() As Variant
remarkRange= wb.Sheets("wb").Range("A1:A5").Value2 

For I = LBound(remarkRange) To UBound(remarkRange)
   If (some condition is true) then
       remarkRange(I, 1).Delete
   End If
Next I
```

I expected the element in the specific cell in the array to be empty, but I got error 424

Comment: When deleting, you need to move from the end to the beginning, or you run off them end of the array, which means that `remarkRange` returns nothing towrard the end and you're calling `Delete` on an invalid range.. Reverse your loop to go from UBound() to LBound() instead with a -1 step.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the suggestion. Is there another way to do it since before executing the **If condition** , there is others condition that i need to check, where the counter **I** will affect my output. I did try to set  **remarkRange(I, 1)=" "** where is the condition is true is will set the specific element in array to **""**. 


May i know your suggestion about this? Thankss.

Comment: I don't know why the `if` changes anything, but I don't know what *there is other condition that I need to check* means. You've asked why you're getting the error you're getting, and I've explained that and given you a way to prevent it. I'm not sure why `if (some condition is true)` would be affected by reversing the order of the loop.

Comment: An array doesn't have a `Delete` method, so you can't `Delete` an element from it. What do you want to do with the array? Changing one element to `""` might be an option. Note that it's confusing to call your array a `Range`. Maybe consider a different name entirely.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks brother, your solution did help me to solve my error, but the output of using this way is not the output that I expected. Thanks, I learned new stuff again, Happy Learning <3

Comment: Maybe Dictionary or ArrayList will be more suitable for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array doesn't have a `Delete` method. It's also misleading to have the `Range` in `remarkRange` when it's an array, not a `Range`. Maybe a different name, e.g. `remarks` or whatever is clear to you.

If you're going to write the array back to the worksheet, then I see no problem changing an element to a blank string.

```
For i = LBound(remarks, 1) To UBound(remarks, 1)
    If some condition Then
        remarks(i, 1) = ""
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'll need to decide what you mean by 'delete'. I'm not aware of a `Delete` property of an array of variants so while your code might compile it would throw an object required error.

However, your point about previously using the `Clear` method on a `Range` object, suggests that you just want to read your range values into an array, remove the contents if certain conditions aren't me, and then re-write your array to the range. If that's the case, you probably wouldn't want to resize your array as the rows or columns wouldn't line up - more commonly, you'd set the item of your variant array to `Empty`.

The code below shows how to do this in a simple routine of taking 10 numbers from column A, removing all odd numbers and re-writing the numbers to Column C - but with the rows still matching:

```
Public Sub EmptyItemsAndKeepArraySize()
    Dim inArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Read range into arrays.
    inArr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value2

    'Clear all numbers that are not even.
    For i = 1 To UBound(inArr, 1)
        If inArr(i, 1) Mod 2 <> 0 Then inArr(i, 1) = Empty
    Next

    'Write cleared array to column C
    Sheet1.Range("c1").Resize(UBound(inArr, 1)).Value = inArr
End Sub
```

If, however, you really do want to remove and resize your array, then a simple way of doing it is to populate a temporary collection first, resizing an output array and then populating that with the collection items. In the example below the code removes all odd numbers and then writes the array to column B - but as an array reduced in size (ie contiguous rows):

```
Public Sub DeleteItemsAndShrinkArray()
    Dim inArr() As Variant, outArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Collection
    Dim v As Variant

    'Read range into arrays.
    inArr = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value2

    'Keep all even numbers in a temporary collection.
    Set temp = New Collection
    For i = 1 To UBound(inArr, 1)
        If inArr(i, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then temp.Add inArr(i, 1)
    Next

    'Dimension the output array.
    ReDim outArr(1 To temp.Count, 1 To 1)

    'Populate new array from temp collection.
    i = 1
    For Each v In temp
        outArr(i, 1) = v
        i = i + 1
    Next

    'Write reduced array to column B
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1)).Value = outArr

End Sub
```